# finding the decomposition of Laplacian matrix with position of zero elements unchanged

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'd like to know whether it's possible to find the decomposition of a Lapalacian matrix $A$

$B^TB = A$

where $B$ has the same dimension with $A$ and the position of zero elements in $B$ is the same with that in $A$ or slightly changed.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but this seems very unlikely in general, because zero entries in $B$ tend to become nonzero entries in $B^TB$. So, unless $A$ has very few zero entries, number of zero elements in $B$ would be very different from the number of zero elements in $A$.

Comment: @user1551  but if you think the opposite, the non-zeros in $A$ can be zeros in $B$, thus $B$ can be a more sparse matrix than $A$ with zero elements in $A$ unchanged.